# is it possible to use the newest jedis in spring project

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data

when I force the jedis to use the newest verson 4.2.3 in `build.gradle` like this:

```
resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                
                if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients' && details.requested.name == 'jedis' ) {
                    details.useVersion("4.2.3")
                }
            }
        }
```

the spring project shows error like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis.clients.jedis.GeoUnit
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<clinit>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:93) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.JedisConnectionConfiguration.createJedisConnectionFactory(JedisConnectionConfiguration.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.JedisConnectionConfiguration.redisConnectionFactory(JedisConnectionConfiguration.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar!/:2.6.7]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$316/0x0000000070e22f90.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I want to use the xpending feature of jedis, seems the spring boot data is not compatible with the newest jedis. is it possible to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, NO.

There are some users [[1](https://blog.csdn.net/yiifaa/article/details/73243598)][[2](https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/2781#issuecomment-1027203579)][[3](https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/2781#issuecomment-1032632503)] who are using Jedis 4 but this is possible IFF you are not using some certain features and are willing to go through some extra works.

---

BTW, spring-data-redis is on the way of [upgrading their support to Jedis 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/2287). Perhaps, you can wait for this upgrade.