# Springboot with Redis Sentinals getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am not able to connect with Redis Sentinal nodes using Spring boot. I am getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException while creating bean cacheManager and localCacheManager. I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me out.

Using Spring boot version - 2.6. Maven dependencies are -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Code -**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig {
    
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisCacheConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profiles;
    
    @Value("${redis.sentinel.nodes}")
    private String sentinelNodes;

    @Value("${redis.sentinel.password}")
    private String redisPassword;

    @Value("${redis.sentinel.master.name}")
    private String redisMasterName;
    
    @Value("${redis.sentinel.master.node}")
    private String redisMasterNode;

    @Value("${redis.sentinel.port}")
    private Integer redisSentinelPort;
    
    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private Integer redisPort;

    @Value("${pool.max.wait.seconds}")
    public int secondsToWait;

    @Value("${pool.max.total}")
    public int maxTotal;

    @Value("${pool.max.idle}")
    public int maxIdle;

    @Value("${pool.min.idle}")
    public int minIdle;
    
    public String cacheNames;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {    
       if(!StringUtils.hasLength(profiles)) {
           if(profiles.toLowerCase().contains("dev")) {
               cacheNames = ":DEV:";
           } else if(profiles.toLowerCase().contains("qa")) {
               cacheNames = ":PROD:";
           } 
       }
      
       RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory())
       .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration
       .defaultCacheConfig().prefixCacheNameWith(cacheNames)).build();
       
            return cacheManager(redisTemplate);
    }
  
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = null;
        try {
            long seconds=secondsToWait * 1000L;

            JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();

            poolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);

            poolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);

            poolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);

            poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);

            poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);

            poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);

            poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(seconds);
            
            factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig(), poolConfig);
            
            factory.setUsePool(true);
    
            factory.setPassword(redisPassword);
         
            factory.setPort(redisPort);
            
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();

      } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return factory;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig() {
        
         
        String[] nodes = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(sentinelNodes);
        logger.info("===================== Connecting to Redis 3 =====================");
        logger.info(Arrays.toString(nodes));
        
        final RedisSentinelConfiguration SENTINEL_CONFIG = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master(redisMasterName).sentinel(redisMasterNode, redisSentinelPort);
        
        SENTINEL_CONFIG.setPassword(redisPassword);
        
        for (String node : nodes) {
            SENTINEL_CONFIG.sentinel(node, redisSentinelPort);
        }
        return SENTINEL_CONFIG;
    }
}
```

**Code (RedisTemplate) -**

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Long>(Long.class));
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

**Error code I am getting below -**

> cancelling refresh attempt: creating bean with name
> 'localCacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'redisCacheManager';
>
> nested exception Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined
> in class path resource [com/RedisCacheConfig.class]:
>
> nested exception  Error creating bean with name 'stringRedisTemplate'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stringRedisTemplate'
> parameter 0;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error
> creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path
> resource [com/abc/mbile/xyz/RedisCacheConfig.class]:  Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]:
> Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception;
>
> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> redis/clients/jedis/GeoUnit

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use Jedis 4.x with Spring boot 2.x.
It could be a [difficult job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196183/4021802) to use Jedis 4.x with Spring boot 2.x.

> There are some users who are using Jedis 4 but this is possible IFF you are not using some certain features and are willing to go through some extra works.

Until Spring releases support for Jedis 4, you may consider sticking to Jedis 3.x.